# searching within text of api

Tags: php, string, json, api, search

I'm trying to use an api and I'm just learning how to actually implement an api using php, hopefully I'll learn to incorporate jquery. I know how to create a simple search feature through mysql and its data with php, but is there a way to create search within the api? with API, there's json/xml responses, and they're all strings, so I was wondering if the user was able to search those strings?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to post your code and name the API you are using.

Comment: I don't have any code set up because I don't know if its possible, But i'm trying to use groupon's api http://sites.google.com/site/grouponapiv2/api-resources/deals . is it possible to search through the text of the json response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to send the json data to php via AJAX.  Something like this:

```
  var request;
  function runAjax(JSONstring)
  {
    // function returns "AJAX" object, depending on web browser
    // this is not native JS function!
    request = getHTTPObject();
    request.onreadystatechange = sendData;
    request.open("GET", "parser.php?json="+JSONstring, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  // function is executed when var request state changes
  function sendData()
  {
    // if request object received response
    if(request.readyState == 4)
    {
    // parser.php response
    var JSONtext = request.responseText;
    // convert received string to JavaScript object
    var JSONobject = JSON.parse(JSONtext);

    // notice how variables are used
    var msg = "Number of errors: "+JSONobject.errorsNum+
        "\n- "+JSONobject.error[0]+
        "\n- "+JSONobject.error[1];

    alert(msg);
    }
  }
```

You then can call the variable that javascript creates by calling the $_GET['json'] variable.

```
strstr($_GET['json'] , $whatEverYourSearchingFor);
```

Comment: Thank you for writing this up for me. But I'm still learning all these stuff. I've taught myself php, and a little jquery. is there a way to do this in php? if not I'll try to learn this. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem.  JSON is an acronym for JavaScript Object Notation as I'm sure you know.  Javascript is client side code.  Php is server side code.  Therefore you have to bridge the gap and send the data on the client side (the web browser) to your server which runs the php.  That's what the javascript functions are about.  The strstr is a php function calling the variable sent to you by the client javascript.  I hope that's clearer.  Feel free to ask for more clarification if it isn't.

Comment: No problem.  Good luck.  Don't be afraid to learn new things.  The worst that happens is you get an apache error right?